# Remove replace pipe (|) symbol with comma (,) symbol in spark using python

Tags: python, apache-spark

this `myRDD` data for 2 `rows`:

```
[u'#fields:excDate|schedDate|TZ|custID|muID|tvID|acdID|logonID|agentName|modify|exception|start|stop|LS Oracle Emp ID|Team Lead', u'06152016|06152016|CET|3|3000|1688|87||Ali, AbdElaziz|1465812004|Open|08:00|09:00|101021021|ElDeleify,Hisham']
```

How to replace the `|` with `,` so that i can build the `dataframe`.
Is there any better way to build the `Dataframe` with such data. ?

Comment: The `u'xxx'` hints at python v2, ok. If you simply need replace, why not use it on this list you display say `myRDD`, then `[z.replace('|', ',') for z in myRDD]` should give a new list with stings tha all have comma instead of pipe. Any specific spark-python question may be better answered by other people ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> data = [u'#fields:excDate|schedDate|TZ|custID|muID|tvID|acdID|logonID|agentName|modify|exception|start|stop|LS Oracle Emp ID|Team Lead', u'06152016|06152016|CET|3|3000|1688|87||Ali, AbdElaziz|1465812004|Open|08:00|09:00|101021021|ElDeleify,Hisham']
>>> data = [item.replace("|", ",") for item in data]
>>> data
['#fields:excDate,schedDate,TZ,custID,muID,tvID,acdID,logonID,agentName,modify,exception,start,stop,LS Oracle Emp ID,Team Lead', '06152016,06152016,CET,3,3000,1688,87,,Ali, AbdElaziz,1465812004,Open,08:00,09:00,101021021,ElDeleify,Hisham']
```

Comment: Thanks. this works.Now next question How to  build the dataframe with this now. As column agent name and team lead contains the ",".

Comment: I don't actually know anything about spark or dataframes or anything like that. I just know how to manipulate strings.

Answer (score 2):

according to [spark doc on `createDataFrame`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SQLContext.createDataFrame) one way to create a frame is to pass it data as a list of list and the header as a list.

```
data = [u'#fields:excDate|schedDate|TZ|custID|muID|tvID|acdID|logonID|agentName|modify|exception|start|stop|LS Oracle Emp ID|Team Lead', u'06152016|06152016|CET|3|3000|1688|87||Ali, AbdElaziz|1465812004|Open|08:00|09:00|101021021|ElDeleify,Hisham']

data = [d.split("|") for d in data] #creating a list of list 

shema = data[0] # the first row of the data is the in reality the schema
data = data[1:] # remove the schema from the data
schema[0] =schema[0].split(":",1)[1] #to remove the #fields: of the first header
dataframe = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data,schema)
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't even need a for loop, suppose your string is called 'data':

```
data[0] = data[0].replace('|',',')
```

Done nice and easy in one line.

Comment: Thanks ,The solution will work with single row. but issue is how to replace with multiple rows.

Comment: @SamirMatkar you are welcome, by row you mean string?